# How to write Jquery script in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js

I try code to build Navbar in Vue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isJi6.png)js, while scrolling change color using Jquery and CSS script. This work but, in part .... Vue js not support syntax $, when i refresh page. There error " $ not defined". I'm new here and at Vuejs, sorry if there is a wrong word in the delivery. I hope someone can help me. Thank you :).

This code Vue :

```css
.navbar{
  transition:500ms ease;
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: 600;
} 


.navbar.scrolled {
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
} 

.nav-link {
  color: white;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: lightgray;
}
.nav-link:focus {
  color: lightgray;
}

.navbar-brand.change-black, .nav-link.change-black {
  color:#000;
}

.nav-link.change-black:hover, .nav-link.change-black:focus {
  color:#0d6efd;
}
```

```html
<template>
    <b-app>
        <b-nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg pt-12 pb-12 fixed-top fluid"
        data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="700"
        >
            <b-container>
                    <b-col lg="3">
                        <b-nav-item class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <span>APR</span>
                        </b-nav-item>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col lg="8" class="d-flex"> 
                        <b-nav-item class="nav-link" href="#">Home</b-nav-item>
                        <b-nav-item class="nav-link" href="#">Procedure</b-nav-item>
                        <b-nav-item class="nav-link" href="#">About</b-nav-item>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col lg="1" class="d-flex" right>
                        <b-nav-item-dropdown
                        id="my-nav-dropdown"
                        text="Masuk"
                        toggle-class="nav-link-custom"
                        right
                        >
                            <b-dropdown-item>Lecturer</b-dropdown-item>
                            <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
                            <b-dropdown-item>Secretary</b-dropdown-item>
                        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
                    </b-col>
            </b-container>
        </b-nav> 
    </b-app>
    
</template>

<script>
export default {
        name: 'CoverLayout',
        data () {
            return {
            }
        },
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
$('.navbar').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 50);
$('.nav-link').toggleClass('change-black', $(this).scrollTop() > 50);
$('.navbar-brand').toggleClass('change-black', $(this).scrollTop() > 50);
$('.back-to-top').toggleClass('active', $(this).scrollTop() > 50);
});

</script>
```

[Work if i not refresh page
][Error when i refresh page]

Comment: You _really_ shouldn't be mixing jQuery with Vue. Also, it's 2022: native JS can pretty much do everything jQuery can back then, without needing polyfills. Based on your code, it's a matter of listening to the `scroll` event using `addEventListener`, and then using [`Element.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stay away from jQuery when using Vue. Just stick with plain old vanilla JS. It's more than capable of handling this task by using an event listener.

Something like:

```
const navBar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
const navLink = document.querySelector(".nav-link");
const navBarBrand = document.querySelector(".navbar-brand");
const backToTop = document.querySelector(".back-to-top");

window.addEventListener('scroll',handleScroll);

function handleScroll(){
      let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollY || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if(scrollPosition >50) {
    navbar.classList.add("scrolled");
    navLink.classList.add("change-black");
    navBarBrand.classList.add("change-black");
    backToTop.classList.add("active");
 } else {
    // ... 
 }
 
}
```